# whats the best way to model dependencies in SQL relational database

Tags: database-design

if i have a table called **projects** and a project can have a dependency on one or many other projects, what is the best way to model this in db tables.

i have one table called **Projects** with columns: **ID, Name**

i was thinking of having a new column called Dependencies and just store the ID of another project but i just realized that there can be many project dependencies so i can store this as a comma delimited list of project IDs but i wanted to get opinions on any other way to model this in a relational db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is self-explanatory.

[image: dependency_model_01]

Answer (score 2):

Create a new table called `Dependencies`.  It should have two ID fields (both are Foreign Keys): `Project1ID` and `Project2ID`.  You can include whatever other columns in this table you feel are relevant.

Create one record in the new table for each dependency between one project and another.